# Find Dynamically Added Controls From Gridview in SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a gridview in user control and added the controls dynamically using placeholder
now i find the controls from grid it give that controls are not exist in the grid
Code is as Following :

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
PlaceHolder plc = (PlaceHolder)row.FindControl("lblPlaceHolder");
TextBox txtTextBox1 = plc.FindControl("txtTextBox1") as TextBox; //its give Null 
}
```

can anyone has answer plz

---

Added code from Comments:

```
foreach (GridViewRow dr in GridView1.Rows) 
{ PlaceHolder placeHolder = dr.FindControl("lblPlaceHolder") as PlaceHolder; 
  TextBox txtTextBox1= new TextBox(); 
  txtTextBox1.Width = 300; 
  placeHolder.Controls.Add(txtTextBox1);
}
```

Comment: thank you sir i already try this but still give null value

Comment: Ok, does plc have a value or is it Null also?

Comment: plc have a value its not null

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on it and looked at the Controls Property to make sure it has items in it. i.e. a count ?

Comment: `FindControl` does not recurse into your control's children; it just checks the _direct_ children. Maybe you want to implement your own deep-lookup.

Comment: i put the breakpoint and i get that plc.Controls.Count=0;

Comment: Uwe Keim  can you just explain it more?

Comment: If you do not have any control count.  You have no controls in there. You need to post the code you are using to create your dynamic textbox's and add them to your PlaceHolder.

Comment: i get the control in outpui but not find them on button click event

Comment: Try adding an Id to your TextBox that is what FindControl uses i.e. txtTextBox1.ID = "txtTextBox1"

Comment: @MarkHall still plc.Controls.Count=0;

Comment: I was sure that was the problem, I am out of ideas. I will leave this question for someone more up on the System.Web namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the placeholder, and You will be able to find your controls

and also find your controls using the onRowDatabound, or onRowCreated event from the grid.

---

btw: why is your placeholder called lblPlaceHolder, do You have a label in there and maybe you are asking the wrong contol to find yr textbox, thats why you are getting a null

```
void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = e.Row as GridViewRow;
    if (row != null)
    {

    TableCell myCell = row.Cells[0] as TableCell
    TextBox txtTextBox1= new TextBox(); 
    txtTextBox1.Width = 300; 
    myCell.Controls.Add(txtTextBox1);

    }
}
```

Comment: i added the control dynamically in placeholder how i add control dynamically in gridview without placeholder ?

Comment: no it just a name lblPlaceHolder thare is textbox in the placeholder and i added it dynamically and i also get it in output but when i want to get on button click its give null

Comment: With Row.Controls.Add i got this error :- 'TableRow' cannot have children of type 'TextBox'.

Comment: I have added a code sample, and with row.Cells[0] i mean the first column of the grid, if you are using another column then set the right index of that column

Comment: Hi Johnn, thanks  I add your code its work fine. now can you plz tell me how to find that controls on button click?

Comment: Do You mean that You have a button in one of your columns, if so add the button the same way as the textbox, and use the command event and command arguments to fire the buton

Comment: no johnn my button is outside the gridview and i need all data from grid on its click

Comment: U already have the index of the row in your checkbox attributes, and store that index or indexes, and then onclick of your button get the saved indexes cause the indexes matches the row index of your data